# Search for new questions with no answers and with tags in a list?

Tags: support, search

I am trying to search for new questions with no answers tagged with certain tags, but it does not work as expected.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%28%5Bpython%5D+or+%5Bgit%5D+or+%5Bperl%5D+or+%5Bregex%5D+or+%5Bc%5D+or+%5Bbash%5D+or+%5Byaml%5D%29+answers%3A..1+hasaccepted%3Ano):

```
([python] or [git] or [perl] or [regex] or [c] or [bash] or [yaml]) 
answers:..1 hasaccepted:no
```

But the first question I get was written 50 minutes ago, but if I only search for `[python]` I get more recent questions.

It seems searching for more tags with the `or` operator will exclude some questions. I don't understand why.

How is it possible to get:

- The newest questions (auto-refresh?)
- With any tags in a list
- With no accepted answers
- With few or no answers

Comment: It looks like the search is requiring the first term to be in the question. Even the results that don't have the python tag mention python somewhere in the post. Look what happens when I change the order so that git is first: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=(%5bgit%5d%20or%20%5bpython%5d%20or%20%5bperl%5d%20or%20%5bregex%5d%20or%20%5bc%5d%20or%20%5bbash%5d%20or%20%5byaml%5d)%20answers%3a..1%20hasaccepted%3ano

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem appears to be the parentheses:

[Your search without parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bpython%5d%20or%20%5bgit%5d%20or%20%5bperl%5d%20or%20%5bregex%5d%20or%20%5bc%5d%20or%20%5bbash%5d%20or%20%5byaml%5d%20answers%3a..1%20hasaccepted%3ano) returns results as recent as two minutes ago. It also doesn't matter [which order the tags are in](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bgit%5d%20or%20%5bpython%5d%20or%20%5bperl%5d%20or%20%5bregex%5d%20or%20%5bc%5d%20or%20%5bbash%5d%20or%20%5byaml%5d%20answers%3a..1%20hasaccepted%3ano) unlike the version with them.

The search even describes the search differently. It says this if you include the parentheses:

> Results for [python] or tagged with **git** or  **perl** or **regex** or  **c** or  **bash** or  **yaml** Search options no accepted answer answers<= 1

And this without them:

> Results tagged with **python** or  **git** or  **perl** or  **regex** or  **c** or  **bash** or  **yaml** Search options no accepted answer answers<= 1

It looks like not having a space between the ( and the first [ causes search to not recognize the first term as a tag. You can also fix the search query by just putting [spacing between the parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%28%20%5Bpython%5D%20or%20%5Bgit%5D%20or%20%5Bperl%5D%20or%20%5Bregex%5D%20or%20%5Bc%5D%20or%20%5Bbash%5D%20or%20%5Byaml%5D%20%29%20answers%3A..1%20hasaccepted%3Ano) and the rest of the text.